# how to add ellipsis to a String inside button angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I would like to know how to add an ellipsis to a string inside a button in the given plunkr example. The button width should be 50px.

https://plnkr.co/edit/7PuZ8a52FQs3ix9N4zX0?p=preview

html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tree.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body data-ng-app="testApp" data-ng-controller="button">
    
    <hr>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="save()">SaveFilter</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-Default" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>
    
    <button ng-repeat="name in listofSystems" style="border-radius: 25px; outline-color:#fff;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="{{name.name}}" ng-click="addSystemsButton($event,$index)">{{name.name}}   +</button>
    
    <hr>
    <p><strong>Selected Systems</strong></p>
    <button ng-repeat="name in listofSystemsAdded" style="border-radius: 25px; outline-color:#fff;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="removeSelectedSystemsButton($index)">{{name.name}}    x</button> 
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use `text-overflow:ellipsis` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tree.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body data-ng-app="testApp" data-ng-controller="button">

    <hr>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="save()">SaveFilter</button>
    <button class="chipbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-Default" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>

    <button ng-repeat="name in listofSystems" style="border-radius: 25px; outline-color:#fff;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="{{name.name}}" ng-click="addSystemsButton($event,$index)"><span style="width: 100px;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;display: inline-block;">{{name.name}} </span>    <span style="color:red;vertical-align: top;">+</span></button>

    <hr>
    <p><strong>Selected Systems</strong></p>
    <button ng-repeat="name in listofSystemsAdded" style="border-radius: 25px; outline-color:#fff;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="removeSelectedSystemsButton($index)"> <span style="width: 100px;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;display: inline-block;">{{name.name}} </span>  <span style="color:red;vertical-align: top;">+</span></button> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

added  plus symbol also [check demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XpsfWtin74VsdOnKcPTs?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

the css-way is :

```
.btn {
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  max-width:50px;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Here's demo [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Eaosa0tEaIRZJDdvufKg?p=preview)

Comment: @Anton Stepanenkov thanks for the answer but a small change, with your code i cannot see the + symbol. Along with ellipsis i want to show the + symbol. Any help on this?

Comment: I think best way in here is to add it as an after element, i've updated plunker, you can check there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS

```
.btn-default {
  max-width: 50px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button ng-repeat="name in listofSystems" style="border-radius: 25px; outline-color:#fff;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;width:100px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="{{name.name}}" ng-click="addSystemsButton($event,$index)">{{name.name}}   +</button>
```

Check this if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.text-ellipsis {
  width: 100px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/jbMU2bB4wxRp2GU41GIS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tree.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body data-ng-app="testApp" data-ng-controller="button">

    <hr>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="save()">SaveFilter</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-Default" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>

    <button ng-repeat="name in listofSystems" style="border-radius: 25px; outline-color:#fff;width: 100px;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;display: inline-block;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="{{name.name}}" ng-click="addSystemsButton($event,$index)">{{name.name}}   +</button>

    <hr>
    <p><strong>Selected Systems</strong></p>
    <button ng-repeat="name in listofSystemsAdded" style="border-radius: 25px; outline-color:#fff;width: 100px;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;display: inline-block;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="removeSelectedSystemsButton($index)">{{name.name}}    x</button> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

you can see this on plunker [clickhere plunker link 1](https://embed.plnkr.co/XpsfWtin74VsdOnKcPTs/)   or click here [plunker link 2](https://plnkr.co/edit/XpsfWtin74VsdOnKcPTs?p=preview)

Comment: style="border-radius: 25px; outline-color:#fff;width: 100px;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;display: inline-block;"

Comment: @D V Yogesh thanks for the answer. But i would also like to know along with the ellipsis i want the + symbol also to be shown. Can you help me in that?

Comment: you can check dude     https://plnkr.co/edit/XpsfWtin74VsdOnKcPTs?p=preview

Comment: @D V Yogesh am asking in the button where ellipsis is added i cannot see the + symbol. Along with ellipsis on the button i want to see + as well.

Comment: i  have posted another anwer see that dude looks like                          <button ng-repeat="name in listofSystemsAdded" style="border-radius: 25px; outline-color:#fff;width: 100px;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;display: inline-block;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="removeSelectedSystemsButton($index)">{{name.name}}    x</button>